# Break on all calls to an external module/DLL

Tags: c, visual-studio

Is there any way to set a break point at the module level in Visual Studio so any calls to any functions defined in that particular DLL (3rd party, no source, no symbols) will trigger a break point before calling into the function?

I know you can break on a function name however I need all functions in a module (I could even make do with a wildcard as most of the API calls have a similar prefix)

*Edit:* If that's not possible can a callers graph be generated so I can find all the calls to the API used by my application?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, add this to the question so hopefully I can get an answer "is there any way to get a "callers graph" to list all the calls to the module"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your original question, but this might help with what you ask in your edit.

Here's a trick I've used in the past to print all function calls and where they get called from. Since you don't have the 3rd party source, it won't be as clean, but you could move the logging statement to the macro and replace function calls with the macro using find/replace to get the same result.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG
#define OriginalFunction(arg) OriginalFunctionDebug(arg, __FILE__, __LINE__)
void OriginalFunctionDebug(int originalArg, char* file, int line) {
    [copy/paste variable declarations since they have to be at the top]
    printf("%s called by %s:%d with arg %d", __FUNCTION__, file, line, arg); // use logging of your choice here
#else
void OriginalFunction(int originalArg) {
#endif
    [rest of function]
```